# Count Top N Records Over Date Range Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that looks like the following:

```
+---------+---------+----------+
|id       |title    |date      |
+---------+---------+----------+
|1        |A        |2017-05-01|
|2        |C        |2017-05-01|
|3        |A        |2017-05-02|
|4        |A        |2017-05-01|
|5        |A        |2017-05-03|
|6        |B        |2017-05-01|
|7        |A        |2017-05-01|
|8        |D        |2017-05-03|
|9        |A        |2017-05-02|
|10       |B        |2017-05-01|
|11       |A        |2017-05-01|
|12       |C        |2017-05-02|
|13       |A        |2017-05-01|
|14       |B        |2017-05-01|
|15       |B        |2017-05-04|
|16       |A        |2017-05-03|
|17       |B        |2017-05-01|
|18       |A        |2017-05-01|
+---------+---------+----------+
```

I would like the query this table and return a count (top 2) by date. So, I want it to return the following:

```
+---------+---------+----------+
|count    |title    |date      |
+---------+---------+----------+
|6        |A        |2017-05-01|
|4        |A        |2017-05-02|
|1        |A        |2017-05-03|
|4        |B        |2017-05-01|
|5        |B        |2017-05-02|
|6        |B        |2017-05-03|
+---------+---------+----------+
```

(The Results may not match what I put in my sample table), but I think the point is probably there.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem requires two aggregations, the first which finds the counts for each title/date combination, and the second which retains the two largest counts for each date.

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT title, date, COUNT(*) AS t_count
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY title, date
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT title, date, t_count,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY date ORDER BY t_count DESC) rn
    FROM cte1
)
SELECT title, date, t_count
FROM cte2
WHERE rn <= 2
```

Comment: You can combine window functions are regular aggregates into a single query.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, but then wouldn't it be harder to read?  Gordon's query doesn't work, by the way, I tested it.

Comment: Gordon forgot the group by in the inner query.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine window functions and aggregation functions in single step:

```
select cnt, title, date
from (select t.date, t.title, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by date order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by t.date, t.title
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2;
```

Comment: you forgot a `group by t.date, t.title` in the inner query